# Assignment compatiblity error in verilog

Tags: verilog, code

```
//Universal shift register..32 bit
// en_out=1 serial out..
//en_out=0..parallel out
module Uni_shft_reg(data_out,
data_in,
s1,s0,
lft_shf,
ryt_shf,
en_out,load,
clk,reset);
output reg [31:0]data_out;
input [31:0]data_in;
input s1,s0,clk,reset,lft_shf,ryt_shf,en_out,load;

reg temp1[31:0],temp2 [31:0],temp3[31:0];
reg f1,f2;


always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)

begin
 if (!reset)
  begin data_out <= 32'd0; end
 else
  begin
   case ({s1,s0})
    2'b00 : data_out <= data_out;
    2'b01 :begin
            if(en_out==1)
             data_out <= {ryt_shf,data_out[31:1]};
            else begin
                     temp1[31] <= ryt_shf;
                     data_out <= temp1;
                     temp1 <= {temp1[30:0],1'b0};
               end

           end
    2'b10 :begin
            case(en_out)
           1'b1: data_out <= {data_out[30:0],lft_shf};

            1'b0: begin
                     temp2[0] <= lft_shf ;
                     data_out <= temp2;

                     temp2 <= {temp2[30:0],1'b0};
 end
             endcase
           end

    2'b11 : begin
            if(en_out==0)
             data_out<=data_in;
            else
                begin
                 if (load)
                 temp3 <= data_in;
                 else
                begin  data_out<= temp3[31];
                 temp3 <= {temp3[30:0],1'b0};end
               end
            endcase
            end
   endcase
  end
end
endmodule
```

this is the code which I have written for universal shift register..
On compiling...I am having an error which I am not able to fix.Please help me out..
thanks.

```
ERROR : Assignment compatible type required for assignment.
```

errors in the line
line 33 , 34 44 46 58 61 63

Answer (score 2):

On line 15, you are declaring arrays:  `reg temp1[31:0],temp2 [31:0],temp3[31:0]` whereas your data_out is a 32 bit vector, not an array.

So, on line 33 you are assigning array value to a single vector value. In ModelSim 10.1d I get

> ** Error: design.sv(33): Case item comparison:  Illegal assignment to type 'reg[31:0]' from type 'reg $[31:0]': Cannot assign an unpacked
>   type to a packed type.

There you go, it says the error happened here : `Cannot assign an unpacked type to a packed type`. You should declare the temp variables like this:

`reg [31:0] temp1,temp2, temp3;`

Also, there is an extra `endcase` syntax on line 61. [Here is your modified code](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2XK)